# How to call double nested reverse foreign key relation in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on forum project. Currently, I need to fetch somehow the latest posts for each category.

My models structure is following (pseudo code):

```
class Category(models.Model):
   ...

class Topic(models.Model):
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   ...

class Post(models.Model):
   topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   ...
```

I need to fetch latest `Post` objects within `Category` model's functions, so I can call it latter on in my template.

With single reverse foreign key call I would do something like:
`category: Category = self.topic_set.all()` but I need to get one level deeper for `Post`.

Is there any smarter way to do it instead of list comprehension like `[topic.post_set.first() for topic in self.topic_set.all()]` ??

Comment: Does the `Post` has a timestamp? How do you know what the last `Post` is?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It has DateTimeField field. I will use it once I find out how to fetch Posts in smart way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two queries with a [**`Subquery`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) that will obtain the latest `Post` per `Topic`:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

post_ids = Topic.objects.filter(
    category=my_category
).values_list(
    Subquery(
        Post.objects.filter(
            topic_id=OuterRef('pk')
        ).order_by('-created').values('pk')[:1]
    ),
    flat=True
)

posts = Post.objects.filter(pk__in=post_ids)
```

Comment: Thanks, it will definately work, but can it be done within single object? I mean, I would prefer to query only the topics related with the certain ```Category``` -> query at model function level.

Comment: @vuka: it works with a single `Category`: that is the `my_category` part.